# How to display a stream of terminal messages on a web GUI using roslibjs?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbridge, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm putting together a web GUI using `roslibjs` and would like to display the stream of terminal messages. I understand I can subscribe to these messages on the `/rosout` topic but can someone provide a minimal working example of how to display these in the webpage?

Currently in my HTML I have:

```
<p>Terminal Message: {{ terminalMessage }}</p>
```

However, this is not picking up the terminal message from the `Vue app` in my `main.js` file. This is confusing because I have other data that can be binded in this way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361130/how-to-display-a-stream-of-terminal-messages-on-a-web-gui-using-roslibjs?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-09-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [biaspoint](https://answers.ros.org/users/65043/biaspoint/) on 2021-05-05**:
Do you mean the console (using the debug option within the browser?) or the actual terminal running on the server side (where the roscore is?)

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2021-05-07**:
I meant the server side where `roscore` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a bit further with this and the following `html` code worked:

```
<div id="terminal_log" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <div class="overflow-auto">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item" v-for="x in terminalMessages">{{ x.line }}</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

where `terminalMessages` is subscribed to in `javascript` with:

```
getTerminalMessages: function (){
    let terminalMessageTopic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
        ros: this.ros,
        name: '/rosout_agg',
        messageType: 'rosgraph_msgs/Log'
    })
    terminalMessageTopic.subscribe((message) => {
        this.terminalMessages.push({line: message.msg});
    })
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2021-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0